# Adding numbers from one table to another using INNER JOINs - help!

Tags: php, sql, join, inner-join, sql-update

I surfed the web and found something similar to what I want but it does not execute...help please

My tables have the following structure:

```
TABLE team
  id integer autoincrement primary key,
  name varchar,
  pointsfavor integer,
  pointscontra integer

TABLE game
  id integer autoincrement primary key,
  team1_id integer,
  team2_id integer,
  score1 integer, /*score for team1*/
  score2 integer /*score for team2*/
```

I have this update statement until now:

```
UPDATE team 
INNER JOIN game g1 ON (team.id = g1.team1_id)
INNER JOIN game g2 ON (team.id = g2.team2_id)
SET pointsfavor = pointsfavor 
      + IF(g1.score1 > g1.score2, g1.score1 - g1.score2, 0) 
      + IF(g2.score2 > g2.score1, g2.score2 - g2.score1, 0)
  , pointscontra = pointscontra 
      + IF(g1.score1 < g1.score2, g1.score2 - g1.score1, 0) 
      + IF(g2.score2 < g2.score1, g2.score1 - g2.score2, 0)
WHERE g1.id = 1;
```

When I put it in my sql it executes the function but it does not alter my 'pointsfavor' and 'pointscontra' fields from team... so it says, affected rows (0)....

Look:

[image: my current query]

Here are the values that I entered in **game** table (score1 & score2):

[image: game table]

and here is the **team** table after I excecute the code...is stays the same:

[image: team table]

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Use left join instead of inner join:

```
UPDATE team 
LEFT JOIN game g1 ON (team.id = g1.team1_id)
LEFT JOIN game g2 ON (team.id = g2.team2_id)
SET pointsfavor = pointsfavor 
      + IF(g1.score1 > g1.score2, g1.score1 - g1.score2, 0) 
      + IF(g2.score2 > g2.score1, g2.score2 - g2.score1, 0)
  , pointscontra = pointscontra 
      + IF(g1.score1 < g1.score2, g1.score2 - g1.score1, 0) 
      + IF(g2.score2 < g2.score1, g2.score1 - g2.score2, 0)
WHERE g1.id = 1;
```

I don't know what's your table fields or how your code works but i guess your problem is in your if statement 
For example in first update ( pointsfavor ) IF g1.score1 > g1.score2 then g1.score1 - g1.score2 and also in second if, But in Second update when g1.score1 > g1.score2 Then pointscontra + 0 + 0 and next if also do same thing -  then in this query just pointsfavor has affected 
So when first clause statement ( pointsfavor ) be correct then second clause statment is incorrect !
take a Look at your code agian ;)

Comment: thnx... it only updated pointsfavor from team.id = 1 though...any answers on that?

Comment: I don't know what's your table fields or how your code works but in guess your problem is in your if statment :

Answer (score 0):

Two updates (one per team):

```
UPDATE team t1
SET t1.pointsfavor = t1.pointsfavor + IF(game.score1 > game.score2, game.score1 - game.score2, 0)
, t1.pointscontra = t1.pointscontra + IF(game.score2 > game.score1, game.score2 - game.score1, 0)
FROM team
INNER JOIN game ON game.team1_id=t1.id
WHERE game.id = 1

UPDATE team t2
SET t2.pointsfavor = t2.pointsfavor + IF(game.score2 > game.score1, game.score2 - game.score1, 0)
, t2.pointscontra = t2.pointscontra + IF(game.score1 > game.score2, game.score1 - game.score2, 0)    
FROM team
INNER JOIN game ON game.team2_id=t2.id
WHERE game.id = 1
```